# RNN with GRU in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

I want to implement Recurrent Neural network with GRU using Keras in python. I have problem in running code and I change variables more and more but it doesn't work. Do you have an idea for solve it?

```
inputs = 42          #number of columns input  
num_hidden =50      #number of neurons in the layer
outputs = 1           #number of columns output  
num_epochs = 50
batch_size = 1000
learning_rate = 0.05
#train       (125973, 42)  125973 Rows and 42 Features
#Labels  (125973,1) is True Results
model = tf.contrib.keras.models.Sequential()
fv=tf.contrib.keras.layers.GRU
model.add(fv(units=42, activation='tanh', input_shape= (1000,42),return_sequences=True))  #i want to send Batches to train


#model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.15))  # Dropout overfitting

#model.add(fv((1,42),activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Dropout overfitting

model.add(fv(42, activation='tanh'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.15))  # Dropout overfitting

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000,activation='softsign'))
#model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation("softsign"))


start = time.time()
# sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
# model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=sgd)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="Adam") 
inp = np.array(train)
oup = np.array(labels)
X_tr = inp[:batch_size].reshape(-1, batch_size, inputs)
model.fit(X_tr,labels,epochs=20, batch_size=batch_size)
```

However I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense to have shape (1000,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Comment: could you tell me how can i change it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have mentioned input vector shape to be 1000.

`model.add(fv(units=42, activation='tanh', input_shape= (1000,42),return_sequences=True))  #i want to send Batches to train`

However, shape of your training data (X_tr) is 1-D
Check your X_tr variable and have same dimension for input layer.

Comment: X_tr is (1, 1000, 42)

Comment: i dont Know im confusing really

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error carefully you would realize there is a shape mismatch between the shapes of labels you provide, which is `(None, 1)`, and the shape of output of model, which is `(None, 1)`:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target:  <--- This means the output shapes
expected dense to have shape (1000,)     <--- output shape of model  
but got array with shape (1,)            <--- the shape of labels you give when training
```

Therefore you need to make them consistent. You just need to change the number of units in the last layer to 1 since there is one output per input sample:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softsign')) # 1 unit in the output
```

Comment: i change it but Error accure   ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 125973 target samples.

Comment: @Mahdi.m Make sure the input data (`X_tr`) has a shape of `(num_samples, num_timesteps, num_features)` and the shape of labels array (`labels`) is `(num_samples,)` or `(num_samples, 1)`.

Comment: X_tr.shape,label.shape    ((1000, 1, 42), (1000, 1))   ValueError: Error when checking input: expected gru_4_input to have shape (1000, 42) but got array with shape (1, 42)

Comment: @Mahdi.m Change input shape of GRU layer to `(1, 42)`.

Comment: its Work!!!Thank  you         i have one question how can i send batches to train it?should i use loop for?could you tell me about it?

Comment: @Mahdi.m Actually the training is done in batches by default when you call `fit` method. You can specify the `batch_size` argument in the `fit` call to control the amount of input samples used in each batch.

Comment: its GOOD! thank you    its running  but loss variable is 99! why its happen?

Comment: i have another question ....   i have 100000 data for train and batch of data 1000   and when i run it loss function is 100!! why it happen?